# How do I set the initial value of an accumulator in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've written a function `r` that represents a functional state `s` update, of the form `s: r[s;q]`

I'm trying to get it to scan a list of integers `q`, but the problem I'm getting is that the application of scan `/` consumes the first and second digits of the list, rather than the initial state `s`. The result should be a list of states.

What am I doing wrong?

Actual code:

```
a: 5+cos (til 20)
s: `peg`ent`exi!3#enlist[::]
r: {[s;q]
  l: 0.9; h: 1.1;
  init: `peg`ent`exi!({null x};{null x}; {null x});
  s1: `peg`ent`exi!({not null x};{null x}; {null x});
  s2: `peg`ent`exi!({not null x};{not null x}; {null x});

  s: $[all init@'s; s, enlist[`peg]!enlist[q];s];
  s: $[(all s1@'s) & q<l*s[`peg]; s, enlist[`ent]!enlist[q];s];
  s: $[(all s2@'s) & q>h*s[`peg]; s, enlist[`exi]!enlist[q];s];
  s
  }

r scan a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was to set the first value of the list to the state:

```
r scan enlist[s], a
```

Comment: Yes, or equivalently (and more conventionally) you can write it as `r\[s;a]` or `s r\a`